# Correct way to use ViewModel from child activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel

My application have abstract activity class (`BaseQueueActivity`) implementing most of activity needed functionality. Class is also using one `ViewModel` class and one repository class. But now I need to create child activity which will call another API function (call `listAnotherDocQueue` instead of `listDocQueue`). What is the correct way to do it? Should I create new child `ViewModel` and override the `loadDocuments` function? I need to preserve other code that could be in *master* `ViewModel`.

**Base activity**

```
public abstract class BaseQueueActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new QueueViewModelFactory(documentTypes)).get(QueueViewModel.class);

        viewModel.documents.observe(
                this,
                response -> {
                    showDocuments();
                }
        );
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class QueueViewModel extends ViewModel {
    final private QueueRepository repository = new QueueRepository();

    private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Models.QueueDoc>> _documents = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public LiveData<ArrayList<Models.QueueDoc>> documents = _documents;

    public QueueViewModel() {
    }

    public void loadDocuments() {
        loadDocuments("");
    }
    public void loadDocuments(String search) {
        Single<ArrayList<Models.QueueDoc>> response = repository.loadDocuments(_documentTypes.getValue(), search);
        Disposable disposable = response
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(
                it -> {
                    _documents.postValue(it);
                },
                it -> {
                    // some error handling
                }
            );
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class QueueRepository {
    fun loadDocuments(documentTypes: ArrayList<DocumentType>, search: String) {
        return RESTConnection.getService().listDocQueue(documentTypesString, search)
    }
}
```

**Retrofit API**

```
@GET("listDocQueue/{DocType}/{Search}")
Single<ArrayList<Models.QueueDoc>> listDocQueue(
        @Path("DocType") String DocType,
        @Path("Search") String search);

@GET("listAnotherDocQueue/{DocType}/{Search}")
Single<ArrayList<Models.QueueDoc>> listDocQueue(
        @Path("DocType") String DocType,
        @Path("Search") String search);
```

Comment: You're starting to run into the unnecessary complexity that happens when you try to use BaseActivities. Someone below is even suggesting you compound the complexity by introducing BaseViewModels. Read the links here for some explanations of why I think this should be avoided entirely. Composition over inheritance. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75007744/506796

Comment: Thanks for comment. Composition is nice idea, but I don't think I will use it in this scenario. This base class is doing exactly what I need (just load some data and show the list of it) so rewritting to composion what probably does not add any benefits right now. But I will this for other parts of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce the base view model

```
abstract class BaseActivityViewModel: ViewModel() {
 abstract fun listDocQueue()
}
```

Your base activity class could be generic and have a method to create a view model instance:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<ViewModelT: BaseActivityViewModel>: Activity {
  protected open fun getViewModelFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory? = null

  protected val viewModel: ViewModelT by lazy {
      val viewModelFactory = getViewModelFactory()
      if(viewModelFactory != null) {
         ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(viewModelClass)
      } else {
         ViewModelProvider(this).get(viewModelClass)
      }
  }
}
```

Then define your ViewModels and Activities based on your needs

```
class ActivityViewModel1 : BaseActivityViewModel() {
   override fun listDocQueue() { ... }
}

class ActivityViewModel2 : BaseActivityViewModel() {
   override fun listDocQueue() { ... }
}
```

```
class Activity1: class BaseActivity<ActivityViewModel1>() {
   override onCreate(...) {
      onCreate(...)
      viewModel.listDocQueue()
}

class Activity2: class BaseActivity<ActivityViewModel2>() {
   override onCreate(...) {
      onCreate(...)
      viewModel.listDocQueue()
}
```

Also make sure you have provided ViewModelFactory in case you need that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest architecture guidelines you should be passing usecases to the viewModel, instead of exposing repository and each Use-case handles a specific task. it makes testing and maintaining code very easy. I recommend you use some kind of dependency inject as-well I personally use Dagger-Hilt. it makes it very easy.

Repository

```
interface Repository {}
```

Repositoryimpl

```
class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val Dao: Dao) : Repository {}
```

UseCase

```
class getWordFromRep(
private val repository: Repository) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(){
      repository.getWord()
   } 
}
```

Than in ViewModel

```
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
     private val getWord: GetWordFromRep
   ) : ViewModel(){
     fun getWord() = getword()
}
```

And for Di you will be making a module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideGetWordFromRep(repository: RepositoryImpl) = GetWordFromRep(repository)
}
```

I recommend you watch the use-case video by [Philipp Lackner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufq3LJ-5P6s) It really helped me understand it.

Also I recommend using Flows and states instead of livedata it really makes getting data in views easier and makes the code much cleaner.